# Removing Email Field during registration in Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using    the RTM version 2.0 of the new Identity framework.
I do not want to use email field in registration , instead of that i want  username..
How can i do that??

Answer (score 0):

If you have update for identity than update, because new version has username field.
http://anthonychu.ca/post/aspnet-identity-20---logging-in-with-email-or-username